# Ffmpeg: Move a slider "image" over a "background" from 0% to 100% in sync with the audio

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, filtering

I'm trying to create a video using the follwing code:

```
`$`ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 5 -i video.png -r 5 -i progress.png -filter_complex "overlay=x='if(gte(t,0), -W+(t)*5, NAN)':y=H-h" -i video.mp3 -acodec copy video.mp4
```

I have the following files

- video.png [image: http://i.imgur.com/pmwnaLV.png]

  - this is a 1280x720 px still frame that is simply a background with a waveform of the video.mp3 file
- progress.png [image: http://i.imgur.com/qXltKR2.png]

  - this is simply a 1280x100 px semi-transparent image that should simulate an animation (from from 0 to 100% of the width of the video.png file, in order to simulate "fill up" animation.

My issues are as following:

- The video is not in sync with the audio. The progress bar is way off, instead of finishing at the end of the song, it just keeps going on and on and on and on...
- Also... it just keeps going on and on! I left it create a 1 hour video and it never stopped.

I know I'm missing something in the filter, but I have no idea how I could fix it.

Could someone lend me some help?

Comment: Use `-shortest` to end after the shortest stream (the audio in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Pranav said, use `-shortest` at the end of the stream to sort the duration issue.

Now to sync the progress of your frame you've got to figure out how much your overlayed picture needs to move per second. This is simple: you need to move your picture by "Width of your video / Duration of your video"

For instance if you've got a 3 minutes song and a video width of 1280:

- 3 minutes = 3x60 = 180 seconds.
- "Width of your video / Duration of your video" = 1280 / 180 = 7.11 pixels / second.

`7.11` is the value to use instead of `5` in `-W+(t)*5,`.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks.

I managed to figure this out by myself eventually (just didn't really think of marking it as answered on StackOverflow, much coffee, brain in zombie mode).

The other problem I'm having is that no matter how much I move per second, even if eval is set to frame, the movement will be choppy, even if I'm rendering the output at 25fps or 5fps.

This is one of the debug logs I have: 

http://pastebin.com/bSBiwcLS

As you can see in the "xi" column, the image moves 2 pixels every few seconds. Any ideas how could I make it move more smoothly?

Comment: If you expect a smooth motion the best is to use a framerate that is a multiple of the number of pixels your image is shifted each second. Could you test it in full HD. In case there is an improvement we'll figure out the command line to overlay in full HD and still output a 720p video.

Comment: Also try `-pix_fmt yuv444p` to see if your picture moves pixel by pixel, there's is something about 420 chroma subsampling not liking odd numbers...

Comment: Actually I was thinking of doing it in some other way.

Having the transparent bar animation to be an alpha channel video and overlaying the video (and adjusting for the duration) on the end result.

Just that I'm hitting a brick wall with video formats that support an alpha channel.

Comment: Have you tried ProRes 4444? I never used it but according to this page http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5151 it supports alpha channel.

Comment: QuickTime Animation RLE (`qtrle`) supports an alpha channel.  You can also just use a series of `png` images.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for answering so late!

@AJ29: I decided to give up on the whole overlay video deal and you were spot on.

The overlay filter was processing with yuv420, thus moving the image in 2px increments; setting overlay=format=yuv444 made the animation pixel-by-pixel.

```
ffmpeg -y  -i "wanderhouse - Sugar.mp3" -loop 1 -i frame.png -i waveform.png -i progress.png -filter_complex "[1][2]overlay=x=0:y=H-h:eval=init[over];[over]drawtext=fontfile=impact.ttf:fontsize=72:text='WANDERHOUSE- - SUGAR':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-170-text_h):fontcolor=white:shadowy=2:shadowx=2:shadowcolor=black[text];[text][3] overlay=x='floor(if(lt(-W+(n)*0.248182258846,0), -W+(n)*0.248182258846))':y=H-h:format=yuv444" -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -crf 10 video.mp4 -report
```

Is what I came up in the end. `0.248182258846` is the amount of pixels I have to move the "progress.png" each frame (n).

Thanks for your tips!

@mark4o: I figured that out, eventually. I tried going the qrtle way of creating a video with an alpha channel then setting it on top of my "other" video", but I failed miserably at syncing them and I gave up.

---

The end result of my work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8uHTIXO0p0